# jQuery validation - changing value of max at runtime

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have these validation rules:

```
$("#ed_details").validate({
    rules: {
        tagno: { required: true },
        itemid: { required: true },
        ralno: { required: true },
        feet: { required: true, number: true, min: 0 },
        inches: { required: true, number: true, min: 0 },
        cms: { required: true, number: true, min: 0 },
        length: { required: true, number: true, max: $('#maxlength').val() },
        qty: { required: true }
    }
});
```

This is the field that lengths validates against.  It is text only for testing purposes.  It will be hidden once this is working.

```
<input type="text" name="maxlength" id="maxlength" value="<?=$maxL['ml']?>" />
```

This works fine unless I change the value of maxlength at runtime (which can happen).  The user is selecting an item from a drop down.  Each item has a maximum length of tubing that can be used with it.  When the item changes, the value of maxlength does change on the screen.  However, when the validation runs, I see an error message based on the original length (0 for a new item, whatever the maxlength was at load for an edit).

```
Please enter a value less than or equal to 156.
```

I see this even when the maxlength field shows another value.

If I use Firebug on the field, it shows the original value even after it has been changed.  Also, changing the maxlength field by hand instead of code does not make a difference.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle demo?  Validation occurs `onkeyup`, `onfocusout`, and `onsubmit`.  Does the error message pop up then?

Comment: It occurs on the onsubmit, definitely, showing the old value of maxlength in the error message.

Comment: Show us your code then... the error message typically shows the rule's value, not the field's value.

Comment: I also added two answers since I was not entirely sure what was happening at first.

Comment: Which code?  The code that changes the value of #maxlength?

Comment: I'm asking you to show a complete and concise example.  However, I think my answer below should put you on the right path.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with the rules being added or removed. The rule above (max) does exactly what I need it to do. The problem is max is supposed to get its value from a field which can change. And max keeps using the old value of maxlength even after it is changed.

Comment: Yes... same thing... if the `value` of that `rule` has changed, then you've changed the `rule`.

Comment: Why it keeps using the old value is clearly explained in the first half of my answer.  And if I could see your actual code, I could construct a working demo.

Comment: I see that now.  I did not realize the plugin rules were set only once.  I will set something up on our test server.

Comment: [Added this live and crude demo to my answer below](http://jsfiddle.net/Y565M/).  You can see how my method dynamically updates the rule from "5" to "2".  There is room to improve but it's a "proof of concept".  http://jsfiddle.net/Y565M/

Comment: That got me on the right track. I made some changes:  http://jsfiddle.net/Y565M/6/.  And thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can **not** change `rules` like this...

```
length: { 
    required: true,
    number: true, 
    max: $('#maxlength').val()
},
```

That's because, like most jQuery plugins, `.validate()` is called only **one** time to *initialize* the plugin on your `form`... it does not run repeatedly, so dynamically changing the `rules` options within `.validate()` does nothing.

Use the `rules` method to `add` and update your rules dynamically.  (use along with the code that changes the value.)

```
$('#maxlength').rules("add", {
     max: $('#maxlength').val()
});
```

See this very crude "proof of concept" demo below (room for you to rearrange).  Test the form (value is initially 5).  Then click the button one time and the value and rule (along with message) are updated correctly to "2".

http://jsfiddle.net/Y565M/

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules

Comment: Thanks for this - searched for an hour to find this solution which explains the correct answer as the validate is loaded on initialise. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this too :

```
function ()  { return $("#maxlength").val()  }
```

In this case :

```
length : {  required:  true, number: true, max: function () { return $("#maxlength").val()  }  }
```

Comment: better solution that the approved one

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add sparky method in `change` trigger

```
$('#maxlength').change(function() {
    $('#ed_details').rules('remove', 'length');
    $('#ed_details').rules('add', { length : { required: true, number: true, max: $('#maxlength').val() } });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom validator that passed in the selector for the input that would provide the max value:

```
$.validator.addMethod("MaxFromValue", function (val, ele, arg) {
    var max = $(arg).val();
    return this.optional(ele) || !(val > max);
}, $.format("Value cannot be greater than '{0}'"));
```

- this is untested code...  use with caution *