# jQuery Validation with depends

Tags: jquery

I would like to do validation which depends on other input value in same form.

```
$( "#step1" ).validate({
  rules: {
    weight: {
        required: true,
        max: $('#maxweight'),
        min: 1
    },
...
```

I was reading all documentation: jqueryvalidation.org, but I can not find anything about using other values from form to validate maximum value of other #id.

Thank you in advance for help.

--- EDIT ---

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AT7V3/), I would like to validate weight will depends on maxweight.
Later I would like to do validate with if function:

```
if(maxweight == 10) {
    max: 10
}
else if(maxweight == 20) {
    max: 20
}
```

--- SOLUTION ---

Thanks all for help :) I did it this way: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rUyAx/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
$(".selector").validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
      depends: function(element) {
        // Do what you want to test
        return $("#contactform_email:checked");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

For what you want, here is a link that explains your problem [jQuery validation - changing value of max at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468821/jquery-validation-changing-value-of-max-at-runtime)

And here is the solution : http://jsfiddle.net/rUyAx/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#step1").validate({
    rules: {
        weight: {
            required: true,
            //max: $("#maxweight").val(),
            min: 1
        }
    }
});

$("#submit").click(function(){
   $('#weight').rules("remove", "max");
   $('#weight').rules("add", {
     max: $('#maxweight').val()
   });
   $("#step1").submit();
});

});
```

(I have added an id to your submit button.)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I still do not know how it use in my example.

Comment: Ok :) So this is link to my code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/AT7V3/), I would like to validate weight will depends on maxweight. I did edit in my question above.

Comment: Hmm.... It is working for first using, for example: Max weight: 5, Your weight: 6 - Here is error, so we change Max weight to 10, and still is same error.

Comment: Ok, thanks all for help :) I did it this way: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rUyAx/3/)

Answer (score 2):

try this. this will validate your weight based on the maxweight.

```
$("#step1").validate({
        rules: {
            weight: {
                required: true,
                min: 1,
                depends:function(element){
                    return  $(element).val() < $("#maxweight").val();
                }            
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: With this solution, you do not use the "max" error message. But your solution also works.

Comment: you can always place a error message for the `depends` like the same way you did for `max` age.